# How to Inject CSS or JavaScript to SharePoint Modern page using SPFX on Sharepoint Server 2019

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-2019, spfx-extension

We are using Sharepoint Modern communication site on Sharepoint Server 2019. I am tasked with customizing the out-of-the-box template for header and adding a footer. I was toying with using https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-application-injectcss but I am unable to get it to work. The SPPKG file throws the following error when I deploy it to Sharepoint Server 2019 apps.

> There were errors when validating the App manifest.:Xml Validation Exception: 'The 'IsDomainIsolated' attribute is not declared.' on line '1', position '322'.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create new project because that sample is using spfx 1.8.0. For SharePoint 2019 you have to use spfx ~1.4.0.

I have my own ApplicationCustomizer with custom css inside for branding ShP 2019.

```
import { override } from '@microsoft/decorators';
import { Log } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import { BaseApplicationCustomizer } from '@microsoft/sp-application-base';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import styles from './css/styles.module.scss';
require('./css/styles.module.scss');

export default class BrandingApplicationCustomizer extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<{}> {
  @override
  public async onInit(): Promise<any> {
    try {
      await this.wait('.o365cs-nav-centerAlign');
      if (window.screen.availWidth < 639) {
        $('.o365cs-nav-centerAlign').css({"height":"50px", "cursor":"pointer", "background":"url(https://.../_layouts/15/Intranet.Design/Img/_intranet_logo.png) no-repeat left center"});
    $('.o365cs-nav-centerAlign').click(function() {
      window.location.href = 'https://intranet';
    });
  } else {
    $('.o365cs-nav-centerAlign').html(`
    <div class=` + styles.brandingMainDiv + `>
      <a href='https://intranet' style='line-height: 46px;'>
        <img src='https://intranet./_layouts/15/Intranet.Design/Img/_intranet_logo.png' style='margin: auto;vertical-align: middle;display: inline-block;'/>
      </a>
      <div style='margin-left:15px;border-left:1px solid white;'></div>
      <a href='` + this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + `'>
        <div style='font-family: Segoe UI Regular WestEuropean,Segoe UI,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;line-height: 40px;display: inline-block;font-size: 20px;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;margin: 0px 0 0 25px;vertical-align: top;font-weight: bold;color:white;'>
        ` + this.context.pageContext.web.title + `</div></a></div>
     `);
     }
    } catch (error) {
};
return Promise.resolve();
  }
   private wait = (selector) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const waitForEl = (selector, count = 0) => {
    const el = $(selector);
    if (el.length > 0) {
      resolve(el);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        count++;
        if (count < 1000) {
          waitForEl(selector, count);
        } else {
          reject('Error: More than 1000 attempts to wait for element');
        }
      }, 100);
    }
  };
  waitForEl(selector);
    });
  }
}
```

Css looks like this (in scss you need to use global atribute):

```
:global {
.CanvasZone,
.SPCanvas-canvas {
    max-width: none !important;
}
button[data-automation-id="pageCommandBarNewButton"] {
    display: none !important;
}
body, /* entire body*/
.ms-Nav, /*left navigation pane background*/
#spPageChromeAppDiv /* whole page again*/
{
    background-color: #eeece1  !important;
}
.o365cs-base.o365cs-topnavBGColor-2, /* top bar*/
.o365cs-base .o365cs-nav-rightMenus /* top bar menu right*/
{
    background-color: #17375e !important;
}
#O365_MainLink_Help,
#O365_NavHeader button#O365_MainLink_NavMenu,
#O365_NavHeader button#O365_MainLink_NavMenu_Responsive,
.o365button.o365cs-nav-appTitle.o365cs-topnavText,
.o365cs-nav-topItem.o365cs-rsp-m-hide.o365cs-rsp-tn-hideIfAffordanceOn,
.o365button .o365cs-nav-brandingText,
.o365cs-nav-brandingText /* Top bar Sharepoint text*/
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If I want to put a background image in the header and add a footer, what css class should I use?

Comment: You are welcome. It depends on your code. Just hit browser developer window and play with css and html.

Comment: I got it to work. On SP 2019, you don't have to run 'gulp serve' while compiling the SPFX

Comment: Great. Yes gulp serve is for testing.